# Having Problems running Auto Hot Key in "ahk_class SWT_Window0" windows

Tags: autohotkey

I'm not sure if this is common or not but I cannot get my code to run in this type of window. It works in all of my other windows except for the one, ahk_class SWT_Window0, I want it to work in... go figure.

My code is:

```
RButton::
SendInput {Click 166,350}
return
```

Pretty simple just move the cursor and click. It works in google chrome wundow spy scite and various other windows but not with the correct window. Any help would be awesome thanks!

Comment: Which application is this? A few days ago someone had problems controlling the old MYOB application. I have also seen that some games don't work with AHK. It seems (but I have no hard evidence) that these applications read the low level scan codes directly.

Comment: @Robert Ilbrink It's for the Carbon Poker Client. It would make sense for them to only read low level signals so that they could try to keep people from botting but I just want to use AHK so I can multi table better because the software I was using for this function just dropped its service.

I am decently familiar with python. Are you aware of anything that would, upon me clicking my right mouse button, click an X-Y coordinate of an active window as if the left button was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack,

Have you tried to use the scan codes directly in your application?

Here is an example. It clicks the mouse at the current location and then sends a {Tab}. You need to change this for your needs. You can move your mouse to the right location first with MouseMove,%XPos3%,%YPos3%

```
F8:: ; Press F8 to start macro
Send, {vk01} ; Click left mouse button
;Send, {scYYY} ; 
Send, {vk09sc00F} ; Send the Vk and SC codes for the {Tab} key.
Return
```

Let me know if this works